# Nested Scrolling in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using compose to write a Screen where structure is like this ->
Header, List of ItemA and footer, but each ItemA can have list of itemB..

when i am adding list of itemB in column using forEach, but it causing jerk in scroll.

Please help how can i achieve nested scroll in compose with smooth scroll and good performance.

Thanks.

i am using LazyColumn and adding item{header}, itemForIndexed{ItemA}, item{footer}

itemA -> Column{headerB(), ListOfItemB.forEach{itemB}}

But this causing bad experience in scroll, please help what i can do to improve..